# Getting rid of black spaces after rotating a view

Tags: android, rotation

I have a view which I want to rotate, but it causes the undesired effect of black spaces in the parts of the screen that were occupied by the view before and now are not. How can I make the view occupy these spaces again? This code demonstrates the effect:

```
view.setRotation(60);
view.setRotationX(60);
```

Thanks.

Comment: sorry but this code don't demonstrate anything. Please provide more code. Where do you call this code ?

Comment: In the onCreate function of my activity.